# Swiftmailer size of email

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am looking for a way to get the 'size' (in bytes) of sent emails.

I've been googling around and for now I see a few options:

1. Calculate the size before sending (strlen(body) + sum of size of attachments)
2. Use strlen($message->toString()) and get the size of that
3. Plugins / Build in ways I overlooked.. ?

However I believe that the 2nd one will be worse in performance.

Cookie for thought !

Comment: The only way to know for sure if it is slow is to test both methods. To be honest though, you are unlikely to be sending so many emails simultaneously that performance is a serious issue (unless you are sending spam). I would most likely go for the easiest method (probably `toString()`)  even if it is a little slower.

Comment: If you are reading the attachments from disk (as opposed to generating them on the fly for example) then calling `filesize()` on them is easy and fast, so your method 1 is uncomplicated.

Comment: I'm indeed mostly concerned about attachments, some are from files, some are generated on the spot